# How to import variables (not just values but definitions) from a text file into PHP script?

Tags: php, bash, export

I have a large number of PHP scripts that need a standard set of variables, like `paths` to locations/files. I do not want to hardcode them in every script, neither do I want to define those variables and import their values from a single text file. I want something like `bash` `export`, where I define all my variables and just `export` them into whatever `bash` script I want and start using those variables right away.

One possible solution (that I want to avoid) is, storing the values line by line in a `txt` file and then read those values into some vaariables locally defined inside my php script. For example:

I could store stuff like the following in a txt file named `paths.txt` that reads:

```
/path/to/some/location/
someaddress@somedomain.com
1729
Hello Mars!
etc...
```

then inside `myfile.php`:

```
$all_lines = file("paths.txt");//file in to an array
$location = echo $lines[0];
$rnumber = echo $lines[2];
//...etc
```

But I don't want this!

What I want my `txt` file to look like:

```
$location = "/path/to/some/location/";
$address = "someaddress@somedomain.com";
$rnumber = "1729";
$hello = "Hello Mars!";
```

then inside `myfile.php`:

I just want to directly use those variables defined and declared inside that `paths.txt`, somehow the way we do in bash..like `source` and then `export`

Is this possible?

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks, I will do that from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but it may not be the best practice. Many are using JSON or YAML for these types of things now, it is becoming quite ubiquitous. However, if you want to use the format you're aiming for, just make it a PHP file and include the file as needed.

settings.php

```
<?php
   $location = "/path/to/some/location/";
   $address = "someaddress@somedomain.com";
   $rnumber = "1729";
   $hello = "Hello Mars!";
?>
```

Then require them when needed in another PHP script:

```
<?php
    define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
    require_once(__ROOT__.'/settings.php');

    //more code
?>
```

As an example, you could use JSON like this:

settings.txt

```
{"location":"\/path\/to\/some\/location\/","address":"someaddress@somedomain.com","rnumber":"1729","hello":"Hello Mars!"}
```

Then read in the text file:

```
<?php
    define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
    $json = file_get_contents(__ROOT__.'/settings.txt');

    // make variables from json string
    $settings = json_decode($json, true); // 'true' makes an array, not object
    print_r($settings);
    echo $settings['location'];
?>
```

Which returns:

```
(
    [location] => /path/to/some/location/
    [address] => someaddress@somedomain.com
    [rnumber] => 1729
    [hello] => Hello Mars!
)
/path/to/some/location/
```